# two or more onion domains on the same vps

Tags: configuration, onion-services, onion-routing

I installed a few onion domains: in `/etc/torrc and /var/lib/tor/hidden_services....`  on the same port and configured one virtual host on nginx for these domains (same document root). Usually all the domains work fine. But sometimes **one** of the domains refuses to operate. When I click on its link or enter id directly into address bar I can be waiting for quite long (5, 10, 15 minutes or maybe more, I did not try) with no timeout error or any record in all existing logs. I tried it in new browser tabs. I also restarted nginx and tor.  And nothing helps. At the same time other domains have no problem. After a while it may work again like nothing happened before, and it makes me crazy.
Do you what can be the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you give some more details? Are these v3 onions? If not, try again with them as v3 onions.

Comment: You say that you try a new tab, but are you specifically trying a different route also?

Comment: all V2 addresses. I noticed that I can CURL the address in question from php script or CLI via socks5. So, that means that the problem is highly likely related to routing. If I set another bridge in tor browser it can open the site. Is there any trick in hidden service settings? I did not use and DNS tables, I set up only torrc and hidden service (domain and private key)
Does that mean if I cannot open some another onion site now I can do that in a half an hour or trying to change settings in browser?